# How to get the value from void function in Java?

Tags: java

My problem like this code:

```
public static void main() {
   int a = 5;
   add(5);
   // The value of a is still 5 not 6
}
static void add(int x) {
   x++;
   // x = 6 
}
```

How to get the value as using method by `void` , it is similar:

```
int add(int a) {
return a++;
}
```

What's more:

```
void getValue(int m1, int m2, int m3, . . .) {
//do something which change the value of m
//for example
m1 += 5; 
m2 *= 100; 
...
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question !!!.

Comment: is it a must to have a method with return type void , make a global variable and store the returning value in it , not advisable though

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the value by reference to be able to change it:

```
public class Main {

    static void add(int[] x) {
        x[0] += 1;
    }

    public static void main()
        int[] a = { 5 };
        add(a);
        // a[0] == 6
    }
}
```

---

to fit your edited question, you can simply accept more than one item in your array:

```
void getNewValues(int[] ms) {
    m[0] += 5;
    m[1] *= 100;
    ....
}
```

You can also opt to use a [`MutableInt`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html):

```
void getNewValues(MutableInt m1, MutableInt m2, MutableInt m3, . . .) {
//do something which change the value of m
//for example
    m1.setValue(m1.intValue() + 5); 
    m2.setValue(m2.intValue() * 100); 
...
}
```

Comment: If Author needs to use void (for some weird reason), this is the way to go.

Comment: My problem has many value which must be set value so that using int() - return - it use for only one value.

Comment: @user3714681 - I don't understand - is your problem different than what you stated in your post?

Comment: Indeed; this answers the question asked perfectly. If it does not help you, you asked the wrong question to begin with.

Comment: @user3714681 - updated the answer for multiple values

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types in parameter by default will not have a reference to it that why it is not changing when you increment it by one.

On the other side if it is an object in the parameter then it will have a reference to it and thus change upon accessing and modifying the reference of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead:

```
public static void main()
{
   AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(5);
   add(n);
}

static void add(AtomicInteger n)
{
   n.addAndGet(1);
}
```

Comment: Just tested that, doesn't work either (which kind of surprised me).

Comment: Why does that surprise you? You can't alter the state of immutable objects - that's the whole point behind them.

Comment: I change it using java standard mutable AtomicImteger. My fault: I learn something!

Answer (score 0):

Only object references can be modyfied in such way. You can use something like an object container for a primitive type. Here's an example:

```
class Example {

    private static final int INITIAL_VALUE = 5;

    public static class IntegerContainer {

        private int value;

        public IntegerContainer(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerContainer integerContainer = new IntegerContainer(INITIAL_VALUE);
        incrementInVoidMethod(integerContainer);
        System.out.println(integerContainer.getValue());
    }

    public static void incrementInVoidMethod(IntegerContainer integerContainer) {
        int valueToIncrement = integerContainer.getValue();
        valueToIncrement++;
        integerContainer.setValue(valueToIncrement);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well as you have already said, use a return value!

```
int add(int x){
    return x++;
}
```

Or you can use something like below ! See the code below:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        System.out.println("X is: " + x);
        StringBuilder xStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(x));
        add(xStringBuilder);
        x=Integer.parseInt(xStringBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println("X is: " + x);
    }

    private static void add(StringBuilder x) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(x.toString());
        val++;
        x.delete(0, x.length());
        x.append(Integer.toString(val));
    }
}
```

Well this is a really bad practice! Well I am assuming this is a trick question!! :D
Also, you can use static variable!! This will be used at times...

```
public class test {
    private static int x=10;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("X is: " + x);
        add();
        System.out.println("X is: " + x);
    }

    private static void add() {
        x = x+1;
        System.out.println("X is: " + x);
    }

}
```

Remember to not pass x as argument to add function, the value will be updated inside function but outside it will be the same.
All are tricks , sometimes asked in interview. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh no. It's really my problem.

Comment: I saw you comment that many variables needs to be updated inside the function? Well then the best way is to pass all of them as array and after operation read them back OR use static variable.

Comment: Well. You have understood me. It's a complex problem so I think the full code will help everyone understands throughly my question.